# Breakpoints (strucchange package)

Tags: r, package, time-series, regression

I was wondering if the breakpoints given by the package (strucchange) are corresponding to :
the end of a period, or the beginning of a new one ?
For instance, I have found a breakdate=2003. I assumed that it was the start of the second period, however, when I have integrated 2003 in the regression, I found a better R² than when I included 2003 in the second period.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation refers to the breakpoints as `i_j`,
and the segments are `i_{j-1} + 1, …, i_j`.
In other words, breakpoints correspond to the end of the periods.

You can check it on a simple example: the segments are `1:5` and `6:10`.

```
library(strucchange)
y <- c( rep(0,5), rep(1,5) )
breakpoints(Fstats(y ~ 1))
# ...
# Breakpoints at observation number:
# 5
```